# While fetching table fetching the same table again php, how is it possible?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$result=("select * FROM blablabla ") ;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

{$another=("select * FROM blablabla ") ;
 while($dow = mysql_fetch_array($another)){} }
```

this doesn't work please give me a tip

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually running your queries:

```
$result=mysql_query("select * FROM blablabla ") ;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  // do stuff
}
```

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: no i'm interested is there anithing wrong when i am fetching one table and while doing this connecting and fetching the same table

Answer (score 0):

maybe you mean,

```
$result = mysql_query("select * FROM blablabla ") ;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

}
```

- [mysql_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: this is what i mean and blablabla is the same one table             $result=("select * FROM blablabla ") ;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

{$another=("select * FROM blablabla ") ;
 while($dow = mysql_fetch_array($another)){} }

Answer (score 0):

your while loops should work , u may have some error somewhere else .

look [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730695/multiple-while-loops-within-a-while-loop) where there 3 while loops inside eachother

and my tips is try to debug your code and see where it doesnt work and second tips is try to move to PDO  or MYSQLI